# Docker killed by system when build

Tags: docker, out-of-memory, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I'm trying to build my project on digital ocean droplet with command:

`docker-compose -f dev.yml build`

Log in console:

```
Building node
Step 1/5 : FROM node:6.9.2
 ---> faaadb4aaf9b
Step 2/5 : COPY ./compose/node/entrypoint-dev.sh /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6c22978494e4
Step 3/5 : RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint.sh     && chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in d7e663ef224c
Killed
```

I thought that problem is out of memory, so I created a swap with commands:

```
SWAPFILE=/swapfile [ = Файл подкачки / файл подкачки] 
touch $SWAPFILE
chmod 600 $SWAPFILE
# TODO: pass "count" param to script as argument
dd if=/dev/zero of=$SWAPFILE bs=1024k count=2000
mkswap $SWAPFILE
swapon $SWAPFILE
```

So swap was created, but I still get **Killed** info when trying to run docker build. Why?

Comment: does dmesg say you're out of memory? does the free command show the new memory?

Answer (score 1):

On my system I'm using Docker Desktop and the build system was using more memory than was allocated, 1GB in my case.

Increasing the amount of memory allocated to Docker in the Docker Desktop GUI fixed this problem.

Resources -> Advanced -> Memory

[image: docker desktop overview showing memory usage]

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that tmpfs is filled.

Perhaps try something like:

`mount -o remount,size=10G,noatime /tmp`

Answer (score 0):

For those that follow: At least on my system the problem was that `npm` tried to install the packages locally into an read-only mounted volume in Docker.

So the solution was adding `-g` to `npm` or remove `:ro` in Docker